# Android Studio SearchView UI extending at the right side of the screen

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview, android-search

My SearchView in Android Studio preview looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khyy5.png

But in my physical device, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlrFX.jpg

How can I fix this? Let it not expand on the right side. I only have this code in my xml

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="343dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
```

Comment: Try changing `android:layout_width="343dp"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: @Char already you given margin so remove 343dp and set match_parent as width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to hardcode as much as possible. So, remove the `343dp` width value and replace it with **match_parent**.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

If the parent is a `RelativeLayout` then use this to centre the view:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

And set an overall margin to position it away from the borders.

Answer (score 0):

use Gravity and margin to solve your problem

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using hardcoded as much as possible "343dp" because there are hundreds of screen sizes on every device, If you use "343dp" on a tablet your searchview will become smaller, if you is this on a small screen cellphone, your searchview will become longer.
Change your code to this

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fafafa"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
```